# Using clone() in jQuery to update id and change plus button to minus button

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I searched clone function on StackOverflow I got so many examples. But I'm using it in a different way.

When I click the '+' button it has to clone the entire div and the first div '+' icon has to change to '-' similarly for all of the rows. The reference image is below.

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="container-fluid cloned-row">
<div class="row-fluid">    
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div id="div_form1">
            <input type = "text" id="txt_fname" name="txt_fname" placeholder="First Name"/>
            <select id="opt_sel" name="opt_sel">
                <option value="default">
                    Select
                </option>
                <option value="banana">
                    Bananana
                </option>
            </select>   
            <button id="btn_sub" class="plus"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript code

```
var i=1;
$("#btn_sub").click(function (){
  $(".cloned-row:first").clone().insertAfter(".cloned-row:last")each(function() {
     $(this).attr({
      'id': function(_, id) { return id + i },
      'name': function(_, name) { return name + i },
      'value': ''               
   });     
  });
  i++;
 });
```

And here is my [JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/4u9ud167/2/)

As I am new to jQuery, I am struggling a lot with the cloning function. Also, I am not understanding why the dynamic ID is not generating.

[image: Reference Image]

Comment: So only the *last* of the `.cloned-row` elements should contain a `+` button, all others should have a `-`? Should the class remain `.plus` or should it become `.remove` (or `.minus` or whatever else)?

Comment: Hi David Thomas thank for your reply yes last cloned-row only contains + button and minus button because if i want to delete that row also i have to  delete and the rest will have minus button only :) Sorry for the trouble

Comment: do you have to use clone or can you go another way?

Comment: Thanks amin :) As I am new to jquery when i searched online everybody told that clone will be the best solution If we have any other solutions in simpler way much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS to more easily show/hide elements.  For example, if you add both a plus and minus to each row:

```
<button class="plus"></button>
<button class="minus"></button>
```

this will show a minus for everything, but a plus for the last row:

```
.cloned-row .plus {
     display: none;
}

.cloned-row:last-child .minus {
    display: none;
}

.cloned-row:last-child .plus {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Then use event delegation to handle any click on a `.plus` as "add row"

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4u9ud167/4/